# Lotus Notes' livetext equivalent for Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, lotus-notes

Lotus Notes 8.5 introduced live text, which allows you to configure a text recognizer via regex, so that it can recognize items like flight numbers, fedex codes and make them clickable links that take you to the website.
Is there a similar way to do this in Outlook 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Outlook equivalent to Live Text is Mail apps which can be developed using regular expressions.

Here's a link I found with more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161135.aspx